# No wireless option available in 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10

On my friend's Ubuntu 12.10 (Unity) laptop, there is no longer an option to connect to a wireless network. It used to work. He doesn't know what caused it to go away, but does anyone know how to get it back?

More info:

- See the screenshots below
- No wlan things show up when you run `iwconfig`
- Laptop is HP ProBook 6550b

[image]
[image: Network Settings]

Comment: which hardware you havE?

Comment: @user84277: I updated the question to include the laptop model. But I'm wondering why you believe the hardware might be relevant if the wireless used to work?

Comment: @IanHincks because some wireless devices need drivers that Ubuntu does not come with by default.

Comment: @IanHincks is it broadcom ?

Answer (score 3):

Your laptop model appears to have a Broadcom wireless chipset.

open terminal and type what is shown below

```
sudo apt-get purge broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source bcmwl-kernel-source
```

then type

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Restart your computer after the command is completed and your wireless will start to work :D

Comment: @DavidFoerster The laptop model the OP said they had [*appears* to have](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/Wireless-ProBook-6550b-broadcom-4313/td-p/382955) a Broadcom b4313 chip. Although it would be better if the reasoning in this answer were explained explicitly, I think the inference about the wireless chipset is reasonable. I think we can close this as a duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers).